# New Admin user account password repetitively fails to login in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, user-accounts, language

Strange problem.  From a Windows 7 Admin account I create a new user with admin privileges.  Then I set a new password for the new account and log out of the original Admin account.  Then I try to login to the new user with the password which I just set ... Doesn't work.  I get an incorrect password error.  So,  considering the  possibility  that maybe I just miskeyed when I was setting the new password, I repeat the process. Log back into the original admin account,  set up another new Admin privileged user,  set the password,  log out of admin,  try to log into the new user and get the same wrong password error.

Before any of this occurred  I did notice that the language and keyboard settings for the admin account were set to german.  And,  I changed this on the original admin account before creating the new users. I thought this may have something to do with the new users not working so I verified that I changed the default language, location and keyboard input.

Comment: Did you make an unusual user name with any special characters?

Comment: Yeah, can you type the password you are using in plain text somewhere before you put it in the password field to make sure no weird chars are creeping in.  Notepad would be good as it doesn't support fonts.

Comment: I tried it again via typing into notepad and then into the password fields.  And, created yet another account that I cannot access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did notice that the language and keyboard settings for the admin account were set to german. And, I changed this on the original admin account before creating the new users.

You may have changed the keyboard layout for only that account, and when you get to the login screen you are trying to type the new password with a different layout than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try once again like ,create an Admin account , leaving the password option empty , then try to log-in the new one,after that set password .

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt with admin privilleges and do the following

1. net user **username** * ,where **username** is the username in question or with problems
2. when prompted for password leave it **blank** and press enter and press enter again to confirm
3. that should remove the password for the **username**
4. try login to the **username** and tell us what happens

so that we can analyse it further

alternatively

try enable hidden administrator account using **net user administrator /active:yes** and create new user account to check if your current user account is not goofy